# OSX - Impossible to connect to localhost

Tags: macos, localhost

Since yesterday, everything was working great, but today I can't connect to the localhost on OSX.

I use it to develop local websites, but when I type "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" in my web browser, I have the following message (in Chrome): "localhost don't allow connections".
I don't really understand because I didn't change anything on my computer so I don't really understand why suddenly it's not working anymore…

If anyone could help me, it'd be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your webserver running?

Comment: Yes it is. When I type `sudo apachectl start` in my terminal, it returns `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded`.